# Identifying resistors value

Tags: resistors

I wanted to fix an older divice of my grandma and figured out that a resistor has a crack.
So I tried myself on color-tables but the two gold rings in the middle are confusing to me.
Any hint is appreciated.
Ring-colors from left to right on the picture are violet, gold, gold, black, brown (on a blue body).[image]

Comment: Desolder one leg and measure it's resistance using a multimeter.  That will help identify whether it's a resistor or an inductor.

Comment: @rdtsc did so but I think it really cracked because there is no measurable resistance in terms that its resistance is so big that my multimeter does not recognise it - but thank you for the idea!

Comment: I'd try a 10Ω 5% resistor in it's place. If the original was 1/4W, go the next size up (1/2W). If it were an inductor, the circuit may not work, but it likely would be harmless. The other issue is, why did this component fail and is there more wrong with the board. There is such a thing as a fusible-resistor, perhaps this is one of that type, and has failed as intended.

Comment: @rdtsc - Thank you very much! As the device is something like a small 'onion-chopper' with a fix rpm -> where this resistor is being placed 'in series' directly at the 230VAC input, the 'fusible-resistor'-theory makes most sense to me. Never heard about it before. But after googling 'flameproof resistor 1 ohm' (a synonym of fusible-resistor) a to-me-familiar picture of a resistor showed up. Same ring colours (only violet one missing). I'll definitely try it - but it'll probably take me a while of getting one. Greatly appreciating your input!

Comment: As I was not able to get one of those flameproof resistors I ordered and tried a regular 1/2W 1R - it worked! A big thank you to all of you for your support!

Comment: Welcome. Now go make something delicious with it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can often be hard to figure out.

---

### If it's a resistor:

It's possibly a 1 ohm, 5% resistor as per this [table](https://www.circuitspecialists.com/blog/resistor-color-codes/): -

[image]

Read it as brown (1), black (0), gold (x0.1) = 10 x 0.1 = 1 ohm.

If the final band of violet is to be believed it has a tolerance of 0.1%.

---

### If it's an inductor:

[image]

This might make it 1 uH 5% with the violet band being unknown.